# Failed to set up Travis for my Django project

Tags: django, sqlite, travis-ci

Setting up Travis configuration for my Django project I encountered an error indicating the SQLite version is not supported. To address this I added the sqlite3 service to travis.yml:

```
services:
  - sqlite3
```

Despite this I encountered the following error:

> raise NotSupportedError(
> django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: SQLite 3.21 or later is required (found 3.11.0).

In an attempt to resolve this I modified my requirements file by downgrading Django from version 4.2 to 4.1. This led to another error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
> The command "python manage.py migrate carservice" failed and exited with 1.

Comment: The `(...)` is important to track down the problem in the second error. But I recommend upgrading your SQLite version to 3.21 instead of downgrading to Djagno 4.2.

Comment: Also...you need to fix the formatting. I fixed it twice, but you keep reverting it with your other edits.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.